# Display full image in PopupWindow when clicking GridView item?

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-gridview

I want to display a popup window showing full screen image of the one I just clicked in the GridView.

```
movieBrowser.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        ImageView fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image);
        fullImageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    }
});
```

Here is the image adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is the result of your code and how does it differ from what you want to achieve?

Comment: this code doesn't work fullImageView.setImageResource(mThumbsIds[positon] gives errors, what i want is get the position of the image I click in the GridView and pass it to the ImageView in my popup layout. So it popup Full image.

Comment: You should edit your question and state this there. Also, what errors do occur (best to add the relevant part of LogCat messages). If you want people here to help you, you have to provide all that could be relevant. Nobody here knows your code, nobody knows the errors, nobody knows what you want to achieve and what doesn't work, if you do not tell us, as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
ImageView fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image);
```

To:

```
ImageView fullImageView = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.full_image);
```